# Performing npm install inside bamboo agent

Tags: npm, npm-install, bamboo, bamboo-specs

I need to run `npm install` and `npm run coverage` inside the bamboo plan. I am facing the issue like in some bamboo agents which is picked up dynamically at run time the npm install is happening without any issues and the coverage runs successfully. However, i see that in some agent it fails abruptly. May i know what settings i need to make to overcome this ???

Do i need to add some bamboo environment variables  or something like that ???

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your agents are not all configured the same way, which is normal in some environments.  You should check out the requirements you can put on your plan's jobs. Ideally the agents with node and npm installed have a capability like 'node' or 'nodejs'.  If so, you add these are requirements on the jobs that require the node/npm enviornment and then your builds should work consistently.

Answer (score 0):

you need to share logs - so we can get a over all picture -You need to check concurrent issues as all your agents may be in the same box - I too had similar issues and I used -f instead --f on installation and it cured.